# Python: re.findall won't find a string in html

Tags: python

re.findall won't find a string in html. Here is my code:

```
def get_id(html_source):
    the_button = re.findall("preview.aspx?id=1692003076", html_source)
    print(the_button)
```

When I `print(html_source)` I get the html, which by sight contains "preview.aspx?id=1692003076". re.search also failed to find the string.

I have another re.findall in my code, and it works fine:

```
id_matches = re.findall('<input type="checkbox" id="\d+"', html_source)
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: Your `'?'` is probably causing your issue. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for more info on special characters.

Comment: if you're searching for a string, you shouldn't use `re`.  `.`, `?`, and others are special characters in re.  If you really want to use regex, escape the literal string (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape).  No point in fixing just the `?` - fix the algorithm, not the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the "?" is a special character in regular expressions. You need to escape it.

Comment: @rachelvsamuel How should python distinguish between someone using the feature correctly or incorrectly? A "?" is a valid regex operator so the code is correct, just not what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your special characters in your regex: `.`, `?`. Or, use `html_source.find("preview.aspx?id=1692003076")` to find the first instance of that specific string.

If that doesn't work, post a sample of the HTML in your question so we can reproduce this problem.